# Read Event of Calendar from Android

Tags: android

I have a problem on read event of calendar from Android about begin and end fields of event problem.

**Code:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MyActivity self = this;
    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ReadButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = self.getContentResolver();

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when");

            Uri.Builder builder = uri.buildUpon();

            //Range filter
            Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
            from.setTime(new Date());
            from.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
            from.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
            from.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
            from.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
            to.setTime(from.getTime());
            to.set(Calendar.HOUR,11);
            to.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
            to.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
            to.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 997);

            ContentUris.appendId(builder, from.getTime().getTime());
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, to.getTime().getTime());

            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(), new String[]  {"_id", "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "calendar_id=1", null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");

            if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    final String title = cursor.getString(1);
                    final Date begin =new Date(cursor.getLong(2));
                    final Date end = new Date(cursor.getLong(3));

                    Log.i("ReadCalendar", title);
                    Log.i("ReadCalendar", begin.toString());
                    Log.i("ReadCalendar", end.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

I created a event in google calendar the following is detail
Date: 1-Jul-2013
Title: **Hong Kong Special Administrative Region Establishment Day**
Full Day Event: Checked

When I click a button the flowing is a result from Log windows

```
07-01 16:52:06.491: INFO/ReadCalendar(1357): Hong Kong Special Administrative Region Establishment Day<br/>
07-01 16:52:06.491: INFO/ReadCalendar(1357): **Mon Jul 01 08:00:00 GMT+08:00 2013**<br/>
07-01 16:52:06.501: INFO/ReadCalendar(1357): **Tue Jul 02 08:00:00 GMT+08:00 2013**<br/>
```

The problem is why I got the begin and end day is wrong.  It should be 1-Jul-2013 00:00:00 to 1-Jul-2013 23-59:59

But this event display in calendar is correct.

Please help!!!!

Comment: Any professional can help me?

Comment: No professional in here? OK...I go to another place to ask this question.

Comment: ya I am also looking for this answer .no professional is there for this.If you came to know about this answer please let me know